# « Sur » ou « par rapport à » dans « Quel est l’avantage sur/par rapport à ceux en vente chez Walmart de ciseaux de coiffure de grande marque

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Quel est l’avantage sur ceux en vente chez Walmart de ciseaux de coiffure de grande marque vendus en boutique spécialisée.

> Quel est l’avantage par rapport à ceux en vente chez Walmart de ciseaux de coiffure de grande marque vendus en boutique spécialisée.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

À mon avis les deux options se valent, mais la construction est atroce.

- Quel est l’avantage  de**s** ciseaux de coiffure de grande marque vendus en boutique spécialisée sur ceux en vente chez Walmart.
- Quel est l’avantage de**s** ciseaux de coiffure de grande marque vendus en boutique spécialisée  par rapport à ceux en vente chez Walmart.